# When you self answer should you wait to give time for other answers?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, instant-self-answer

[I was in the middle of writing out a question when I realized a potential solution to my problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552629/double-parameterization?noredirect=1#comment62594133_37552629) So I answered my own question at the same time that I published the original.

One of the comments was that I should have waited to give others a chance to answer. Should I have published the question, waited, then answered?

Comment: If there was something wrong with what you did, Stack Exchange wouldn't have allowed it. They've built in the means to do this, so why shouldn't you? You can't accept the answer yet anyway, so there's still motivation for other answers.

Comment: It's really a matter of opinion. Some think you should give others a "chance", some think that if your desire is really to just share your knowledge, it's a waste of other people's time if you already know the answer and have it prepared, but are just waiting to post it (people might spend time duplicating your effort writing an answer that is superfluous).

Comment: Well, the guidance pointed out in the comment was actually to wait before *accepting* your own answer, not just answering. So you're good.

Comment: I'm with Kendra on this one. The system disallows you from *accepting* your own answer for a while but the button for self-answering is immediately available. If there was a problem with self-answering immediately the site would just not allow you to do it. People commenting that others "should be given a chance" are not understanding how the site works. It's not a competition. We're sharing knowledge. If someone comes up with a better solution than yours they can still get upvotes and you can still accept their answer.

Comment: I don't see any reason to wait to post the answer or to accept it. If someone else thinks they have a better answer, they can post it, and votes will tell over time which answer the community prefers. And of course, you are able to change which answer is accepted if you feel that one added later is a better fit for the question.

Comment: @Don'tPanic To be fair, you _have_ to wait 48 hours to accept your own answer- That's a built-in limit. It's because seeing a question has an accepted answer can actively discourage people from so much as looking at the question, let alone potentially providing a better answer than the accepted one.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks! I think the built-in time limit makes sense for that reason. I meant that I don't think there's a a good reason to wait any longer than you have to.

Comment: @Don'tPanic That I can agree with. :) 2 days is plenty of time for other answers to come in if they're going to.

Comment: @gnat Is it still a duplicate if this question is about etiquette of using the self-answer check box?

Comment: it is a duplicate. Presence of specially designed feature is a firm indication that instant self answering is not only acceptable but even encouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system gives you the ability to instantly answer your own question with the checkbox. Obviously, it can't be considered abuse of the system.

I know that the way that other users view self-answers conflicts with the intentions of the system, however.

Some users may feel like self answers are just a soap box or a "rep cow". But you shouldn't feel this way if you are posting it with the intention that it might help others.

If you are still worried, in your question you can mention (and maybe link to) your answer, saying that you have a solution, but are welcome to other solutions and answers. I feel that this solution also helps avoid potential backlash against the question if it is used as an audit.

Keep in mind that you must wait for two days until you can accept your own answer, you get no rep for accepting instead of the typical +15, and your answer will not be pinned to top (it will move up/down with the votes).

Answer (score -12):

No, its not necessary to wait.

Do post your answer but ***its always good to give it a day***. You might get better answers and if none of the answers satisfy you, you may accept your own answer.

Comment: I disagree.  If you have an answer already you should post it up front so we know.  You do not want to waste other peoples time if they come up with the same answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver What if someone has a better answer? Your answer may not be the best.

Comment: @AniMenon The OP posting their own answer doesn't necessarily mean they think it's the best. Posting their own answer doesn't mean they have to _accept_ their own answer, and they can still upvote other answers that come in. There's a 48 hour delay for accepting your own answer, giving other users plenty of time to decide if they can write a better answer. (Not that they _can't_ if there's an accepted answer, they're just less likely to.)

Comment: Yes but you do not want to withhold one solution and then hope that someone who sees the question doesn't come up with the same solution and post it.

Comment: I agree @Kendra, I meant don't post an answer & accept the same. Do look for other answers.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, thats also right.